# Handler sending message to a dead thread after home button is pressed

Tags: android, handler

I have function that must periodically run on the main thread of the application, and for this I use a *Handler*. The code looks like this:

```
keepDetecting = true;
final Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
          try{
               Utils.log("Detection service is running!");
               myFunctionThatMustRunOnMainThread();
          }
          catch (Exception e) {
              Utils.log(e.getClass().getSimpleName() + ": " + e.getMessage());
          }
          finally{
              if(keepDetecting) {
                   handler.postDelayed(this, DETECTION_INTERVAL);
              }
          }
      }
};
handler.post(runnable);
```

It works all good as long as the application is visible. However, after pressing the home button, I get the exception message: **Handler sending message to a dead thread**.

However, I know that the home button does not stop the application, and does not kill the main thead, so what is happening here?

I'm open to other ways to periodically run my function on the main thread, it needs to work if the user presses the home button as well.

**EDIT:** After further inspection I found that despite the handler throwing this exception once after the home button press, my function keeps getting executed periodically as if nothing happened. So I ended up ignoring this message.

Comment: why don't you use runOnUiThread()?

Comment: @AlexRmcf I placed my function within runOnUiThread, but the same error message still appears. Or should I abandon handler completely? In that case, how can I run it periodically?